# Why we need fragmention in ipv6?

Tags: ipv6

I know that the fragmention for packet in ipv4 is done by router, while in ipv6 is made by host by sending pmtu to discover. The mtu which host can determine the smallest size of mtu so he can just send a packet sutible to these small size so why we need fragmention header in ipv6 if we already known the size!
Why we just send it small without fragmention?

Answer (score 1):

Use of PMTU discovery is merely "strongly recommended" in IPv6, and hence some kind of fragmentation must be supported.

This begs the question of why PMTU discovery isn't mandatory. That's a question for the authors of IPv6, but a few reasons come to mind:

- PMTU discovery adds some latency when communicating with a new peer, which may not be desirable.
- PMTU discovery / management requires some memory in the sender, which in constrained devices may not be  desirable.
- The PMTU between two peers can change; handling this via fragmentation (while subsequent PMTU rediscovery occurs) may be better than stalling communication until the new PMTU is established.
- PMTU might be blocked, e.g. by firewalls. (Though in this case IPv6 suggests degrading to a MTU of 1280 octets rather than fragmenting, but if the real MTU is < 1280 octets - not permitted by IPv6 but possible in, say, IPv6->IPv4 translation) then we'd still need to fragment.)
- Some Layer 4 protocols don't support variable packet sizes, and so fragmentation would be essential if the initial PMTU discovery were unsuccessful.